# NGINX dynamically add/remove configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Background:**
I have a full fledged web service that's performing an *important function* + authentication / authorization and statistics and all that. In case it fails I'd like to enable access to another simpler service that's only performs the *important function*.

Ideally I would think of `location + proxy_pass` that is disabled by default and can be enabled either if some health check URL is unavailable or by nginx cli command with some flag / special local URL

**The problem is:** I couldn't find such functionality it NGINX. What am I missing? 

ps - I am aware that's possible to edit the configuration file automatically + reload, trying to find more elegant solution...

Comment: ...currently exploring -g cli option. will post here if find anyhting

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible in plus version
see documentation
https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-reconfiguration-with-nginx-plus/

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer. However, I'm looking for CE nginx solution.